# Pause a document - HTML, CSS, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a styled HTML version of the typical JS 'alert()' box.

It is simply a nice  that uses 'display: none;' and 'display: block;' to toggle the box.

However, this doesn't have the functionality of a JS 'alert()' box, as doing

```
for(var c = 0; c < 10; c++){ //like the joke? (c++)
    cool.alert('You have seen '+c+' alerts');
}
```

will not create 10 successive alert boxes, but make the box's display 'block' 10 times.

Is there any way to pause the document until the alert box is closed so that the loop would be paused?

Here's all the relevant code:

```html
<button onclick="cool.alert('Hi')">Alert box</button><div id='block'></div>
<div id='box'>
 <p id='text'></p><hr id='hr'>
    <div id='Ok' onclick='cool.alertclear()'>Ok</div>
</div>
<script>
var cover = document.getElementById('block');
var box = document.getElementById('box');
var text = document.getElementById('text');
var ok = document.getElementById('Ok');
var hr = document.getElementById('hr');
var cool = {
    alert: function(input){
     cover.style.display = 'block';
        box.style.display = 'block';
        ok.style.display = 'block';
        text.innerHTML = input;
    },
    alertclear: function(){
     cover.style.display = 'none';
        box.style.display = 'none';
        ok.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
</script>
<style>
#block{
 position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    display: none;
    z-index: 100;
}
#box{
 position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
    left: 35%;
    height: 30%;
    width: 30%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
    box-shadow: 0 0 50px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    display: none;
 z-index: 101;
    color: #000;
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: default;
}
#text{
 height: 60%;
    word-break: break-all;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
#Yes{
 position: absolute;
    bottom: 5%;
    right: 25%;
    height: 15%;
    width: 18%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: linear-gradient(left top, #00FF00, #00DD00);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left top, #00FF00, #00DD00);
    cursor: hand;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: white;
    display: none;
}
#No{
 position: absolute;
    bottom: 5%;
    right: 5%;
    height: 15%;
    width: 18%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: linear-gradient(left top, #ff6c6c, #ff4e4e);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left top, #ff6c6c, #ff4e4e);
    cursor: hand;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: white;
    display: none;
}
#Ok, #Go{
 position: absolute;
    bottom: 5%;
    right: 5%;
    height: 15%;
    width: 18%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: grey;
    cursor: hand;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: white;
    display: none;
}
#Prompt{
 position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    left: 5%;
    height: 40%;
    width: 90%;
    resize: none;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    word-break: break-all;
    display: none;
}
#hr{
 position: relative;
    bottom: 0%;
}
</style>
```

Comment: **Note:** I don't want setTimeout

Comment: If want to use jquery can use .promise().done

Comment: @MoisheLipsker, could you explain in more detail? Where would I put the jQuery? Would I put it in the cool.alert() function? And what do I put it on the end of? $(document) ?

Comment: On second thought, you want it to be when closed. So can perhaps create an event listener that will fire when closed function is called. And instead of for loop would have some global variable that would increment and check if it reached the max times. This might help https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could keep track of the alerts like this:

```
var inputArr = [];
var showing = false;
var cool = {
    alert: function(input){
        if(!showing) {
            cool.show(input);
            showing = true;
        } else {
            inputArr.push(input);
        }
    },
    alertclear: function(){
        cover.style.display = 'none';
        box.style.display = 'none';
        ok.style.display = 'none';
        if(inputArr.length>0) {
           input = inputArr.shift();
           cool.show(input);
        } else {
           showing = false;
        }
    },
    show: function(input) {
        cover.style.display = 'block';
        box.style.display = 'block';
        ok.style.display = 'block';
        text.innerHTML = input;
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, I've tried this with my confirm and prompt functions and it works fine, but when I attempt to call different kinds of dialogues, it will either just do the same kind or give me a 'range error: call stack overflow' (lol)

Comment: I think if you do it this way, you need to wrap it in a class, and create a new instance for the different controls which trigger different dialogs.

Comment: Or make sure that the alert and alertClear functions and same instance of inputArr are used even if called from different object's event handlers.

Comment: I've done that and failed, decided that I won't be needing more than an alert to pop-up in succession. Thanks for the help, I still don't quite get what it all does, but it works which is good enough for me :-)